# Group periods by its name, time and sum_average

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called Periods and I need to create the following structure with its data.

```
{
  name: place_type
  data: [[hour], avg(attendance)]
}
```

Avg = Sum of attendance / number of periods

Example:

```
{
  name: "Swimming Room", 
  data: [["06:00", 10], ["07:00", 16], ["08:00", 28]]
}
```

Basically I need to group the place_type, hour and attendance average.

I Wrote this query but I don't know how to compute the average

```
SELECT 
    SUM(`periods`.`attendance`)/COUNT(*) AS sum_attendance,
    place_types.name AS place_types_name,
    LPAD(HOUR(`periods`.`start_at`), 2, 0) AS rounded_hour

    FROM `periods` LEFT OUTER JOIN `place_types` 
        ON `place_types`.`id` = `periods`.`place_type_id` 
        WHERE `periods`.`location_id` = 131 
            AND (`periods`.`start_at` BETWEEN '2017-06-29 06:00:00' AND '2017-06-29 23:00:00')
        GROUP BY place_types.name, rounded_hour
```

Current result

```
sum_attendance  place_types_name    rounded_hour
1762            swim                14
1587            box                 14
```

The expected result is

```
sum_attendance  place_types_name    rounded_hour
avg         swim                0
avg         swim                1
avg         swim                2
avg         swim                3
avg         swim                4
avg         swim                5
avg         swim                6
avg         swim                7
```

...............
    avg         swim                23

```
avg         box                 1
........
avg         box                 23
```

**UPDATE 1**

Adding COUNT(*) in the divider compute the right average

```
SUM(`periods`.`attendance`)/COUNT(*) AS average_attendance
```

It produce the following result:

```
sum_attendance  place_types_name    rounded_hour
160.1818        cardio              14
158.7000        esteira             14
149.8000        shape               14
```

But it still does not compute to each individual hour.

Comment: What is your input (data sample), because your query looks close to OK (you might want to add a COUNT() to get your divider)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I update the post. Using Count I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work to get the average for each hour when there is data in `periods`:

```
SELECT AVG(p.`attendance`) AS sum_attendance,
       pt.name AS place_types_name,
       LPAD(HOUR(p.`start_at`), 2, 0) AS rounded_hour
FROM `periods` p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     `place_types` pt
      ON pt.`id` = p.`place_type_id` 
WHERE p.`location_id` = 131 AND
      p`.`start_at` BETWEEN '2017-06-29 06:00:00' AND '2017-06-29 23:00:00'
GROUP BY pt.name, rounded_hour;
```

If you don't have data, then the hour will not show up in the result set.

Comment: When I have Periods with the same place_type_id but different hour in start_time it is only grouping the first.
How do I fix that?
e.g.
Period 1 - start_at: 14:19:37
Period 2 - start_at: 18:53:16

Query result only group rounded_hour to 14

Comment: @BrunoFernandes . . . What is the data type of `started_at`?

Comment: The type is DATETIME